# R - Histogram Doesn't show density due to magnitude of the Data

Tags: r

I have a vector called data with length 444000 approximately, and most of the numeric values are between 1 and 100 (almost all of them). I want to draw the histogram and draw the the appropriate density on it. However, when I draw the histogram I get this:

```
hist(data,freq=FALSE)
```

[image]

What can I do to actually see a more detailed histogram? I tried to use the breaks code, it helped, but it's really hard do see the histogram, because it's so small. For example I used breaks = 2000 and got this:

[image]

Is there something that I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Try `plot(density(data))`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I actually need the histogram as well,because I am estimating the parameter, and want to draw the density on the histogram, to show that it's a good fit.

Comment: Can you ignore the outliers? Or do 2 histograms side by side showing 2 different ranges.

Comment: Looks like nearly all your data is is small with a few extreme outliers. If you try to put them all on the same plot this is what you'll get. Why not plot a histogram of the values below a certain threshold? I'm not sure how else you think this plot should look.

Comment: I am pretty new at this and don't know how to deal with a situation like this. To get a better view of the histogram should I ignore the extreme outliers? Is that ok to do?

Comment: Side note: calling your data `data` (or anything that is normally a function) can easily cause problems when you re-run your process/script in a new environment. When you forgot to assign your data to `data`, your script will give you errors about "closures", which tend to be elusive or confusing, and they are because you are trying to treat a base-R function as a data.frame or vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't show data, I'll generate some random data:

```
d <- c(rexp(1e4, 100), runif(100, max=5e4))
hist(d)
```

[image]

Dealing with outliers like this, you can display the histogram of the logs, but that may difficult to interpret:

[image]

If you are okay with showing a subset of the data, then you can filter the outliers out either dynamically (perhaps using `quantile`) or manually. The important thing when showing this visualization in your analysis is that if you *must* remove data for the plot, then be up-front when the removal. (This is terse ... it would also be informative to include the range and/or other properties of the omitted data, but that's subjective and will differ based on the actual data.)

```
quantile(d, seq(0, 1, len=11))
d2 <- d[ d < quantile(d, 0.90) ]
hist(d2)
txt <- sprintf("(%d points shown, %d excluded)", length(d2), length(d) - length(d2))
mtext(txt, side = 1, line = 3, adj = 1)
```

[image]

```
d3 <- d[ d < 10 ]
hist(d3)
txt <- sprintf("(%d points shown, %d excluded)", length(d3), length(d) - length(d3))
mtext(txt, side = 1, line = 3, adj = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply! It helped!